# Verify DexGuard configuration with a signed APK

Tags: android, apk, android-proguard, dexguard

I integrated with **DexGuard** and **ProGuard**, generated a signed APK and now I want to verify that the configuration worked as configured:

1. Use dex2jar (or similar tools) to decompile the app and verify for obfuscation/encryption
2. Verify the signed APK's size is smaller
3. Of course, ensure that the app functions as expected (especially for  encrypted resources)

Are there any other steps folks here use?

Comment: DexGuard and ProGuard? typically you'd use just DexGuard rather than both. Maybe I misunderstand.

Comment: True, I kept ProGuard till I get a better understanding of DexGuard.

Answer (score 1):

In the past I've confirmed the String/class encryption is working by decompiling/unpacking the .apk (I use Apktool) and then grepping/searching the output files for known secrets/API keys etc. In fact this could be automated.

Comment: Ok I'll try Apktool as well. Would you recommend any tools for verifying the APK post-DexGuard, apart from what the docs specify?

Comment: I meant the docs provided with DexGuard JAR, I can't link to them since they aren't hosted anywhere, just bundled with the JAR.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the various tools one can use (copied straight from DexGuard docs when you get their JAR/License):

- dexdump (Android SDK): disassembles Dalvik bytecode to a readable
  text format.
- aapt (Android SDK): disassembles binary resource XML
  files to a readable text format.
- baksmali (open source): disassembles Dalvik bytecode to a readable
  source format.
- smali (open source): assembles this source format
  to Dalvik bytecode again.
- apktool (open source): disassembles and
  assembles entire applications: bytecode, Android manifest files,
  resource files, and assets.
- dex2jar (open source): converts
  Dalvik byte code to Java bytecode.
- jad (free): decompiles Java bytecode to Java source code.

As they always say, read the docs!